# "PDM" is "not declared" as a class of SqlClient.SqlDataReader

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

My code below won't compile, the error message saying that `PDM` is not declared. I'm trying to call a SQL Server stored procedure from vb.net, and the code I have seems to match similar examples that I've found. Why doesn't the `PDM` part work for me?

```
Public Function ReturnPointSource(ByVal PlantName)

    Dim TempList = New ArrayList

    Dim sqlDR As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = PDM.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(GLOBALS.ConnectionString, "sp_readLocation")

    If sqlDR.HasRows Then
        While sqlDR.Read()
            Dim Loc As New Location
            Loc.strFID = sqlDR(0)
            Loc.strFeature = sqlDR(1).ToString
            Loc.intPlantNo = sqlDR(2).ToString
            Loc.strPlantName = sqlDR(3).ToString
            Loc.strMunicipality = sqlDR(4).ToString
            Loc.strRegion = sqlDR(5).ToString
            Loc.strOperator = sqlDR(6).ToString
            Loc.strDistrict = sqlDR(7).ToString
            Loc.strWatercourse = sqlDR(8).ToString
            Loc.dblCapacity = sqlDR(9).ToString
            Loc.dblPopulation = sqlDR(10).ToString
            Loc.strOwnership = sqlDR(11).ToString
            Loc.strOwnerClass = sqlDR(12).ToString
            Loc.strCofNum = sqlDR(13).ToString
            Loc.strComments = sqlDR(14).ToString
            Loc.dblLatitude = sqlDR(15).ToString
            Loc.dblLongitude = sqlDR(16).ToString
            Loc.strSource_Point = sqlDR(17).ToString
            Loc.intSeverity = sqlDR(18).ToString
            Loc.dblSafe_buffer_distance_m = sqlDR(19).ToString
            TempList.Add(Loc)
        End While
    End If

    Return TempList

End Function
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

If you've taken that directly from an example then `PDM` would be something that they have defined themselves.  It's not something that is part of the .NET Framework.  I'm guessing that PDM is the author and `SqlHelper` is a class in their `PDM.Data` namespace.

If you want to get a data reader then you create a `SqlCommand` and then call `ExecuteReader` on it.  That is what that `PDM.Data.SqlHelper` will be doing internally.